# Can I determine the algebraic multiplities from eigen values $0,-i,i$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $ A\in \textrm{M}_4(\mathbb{R})$ and it has eigen values $0,-i,i$. Can I determine the algebraic multiplities from this? My gut is telling me that $0$ must have multiplity 2 and the others 1. Perhaps something to do with the Fundemental Theorem of Algebra as well as a complex root implies complex conjugate roots as well. However this is a vague argument. Can someone help?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892697/how-to-prove-that-for-any-real-nn-matrix-the-eigenvalues-are-real-or-are-a-com)

Comment: If $\chi_A(X)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $X^2+1$ divides $\chi_A(X)$ and $X$ divides $\chi_A(X)$ and  $\chi_A(X)$ has only real coefficients...