# Complex eigenvalues of a matrix in conjugate pairs (or not)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have learnt that in a matrix, if there are complex eigenvalues, they should come as conjugate pairs. Also, I know that, in a diagonal matrix, eigenvalues are the diagonal elements.

So how about the following matrix?

$$\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\ 
 0& 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Shouldn't the eigenvalues be $i$ and $2$, where it doesn't have a conjugate pair?!

I appreciate your help to clarify my mistake.

Comment: complex eigenvalues of a matrix with *real* entries come as conjugate pairs

Comment: What are you taking about this is for real matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ are the zeroes of its characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x) = \det (x I - A)$. Of course it is entirely possible for the roots of $\chi_A$ to not occur in pairs of complex conjugates as shown by your example. However, if we restrict the coefficients of $\chi_A$ to be real (e.g. if your matrix $A$ is real) then we will find that any complex roots occur in pairs of conjugates by the [complex conjugate root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem).

Answer (score 9):

[Complex eigenvalues of matrices with *real* entries come as conjugate pairs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892697/how-to-prove-that-for-any-real-nn-matrix-the-eigenvalues-are-real-or-are-a-com).

This is not necessarily the case for matrices with *complex* entries.

Answer (score 4):

$Av = \lambda v \implies \bar A \bar v = \bar \lambda \bar v $ and so $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$ implies $\bar\lambda$ eigenvalue of $\bar A$.

Thus, *when $A$ is real*, its eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs.